# How can I create a list of files in the current directory and its subdirectories with a given extension?

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a text file that has a list of all files in the current directory and all of its sub-directories with the extension `".asp"`. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll want to use os.walk which will make that trivial.

```
import os

asps = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\web'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.asp'):
            asps.append(file)
```

Comment: Or `asps = [(file for file in files if file.endswith('.asp')) for _,__,files in os.walk(path)]`, which I think would be the "Pythonic" way of doing it (although it's really just slightly shorter syntax for the exact same thing).

Comment: 1 liners are nice but aren't exactly Pythonic in readability.

Comment: This recurses down directories but does not store the paths of the files.

Comment: To store full path replace `asps.append(file)` with `asps.append(os.path.join(root, file))`. Sorry for bumping the dead ;)

Answer (score 4):

walk the tree with [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) and filter content with [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html):

```
import os
import glob

asps = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/dir'):
    asps += glob.glob(os.path.join(root, '*.asp'))
```

or with [`fnmatch.filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter):

```
import fnmatch
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/dir'):
    asps += fnmatch.filter(files, '*.asp')
```

Comment: Like the os.path.join(). I imagine OP will find he needs complete path to the files found.

Comment: When I did your second solution, it just searches the same directory repeatedly. I think it needs this: 

>>> asps=[]
>>> p = r'C:\temp'
>>> for root, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
...     asps += fnmatch.filter([os.path.join(root,file) for file in files], "*.txt")

Comment: Ummm, not quite right. I have the same file in multiple directories under a root directory. It looks like the same directory searched repeatedly but isn't. it still would be better with the path attached, as in your first solution.